# Solution for matrix equation with non-equality

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three matrices where $A$ and $B$ have full column rank. Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be three vectors where $Ax$, $By$ and $Cz$ are well defined.

When $Ax \neq By + Cz$ for any $x \neq 0$, $y \neq 0$ and $z \neq 0$, does this imply $Ax \neq By$ or $Ax \neq  Cz$?? Or, under what conditions, does $Ax \neq By + Cz$  imply $Ax \neq By$ or $Ax \neq  Cz$??

Comment: Take $A$, $B$, $C$ each $n \times 1$, $A = B$ and $C$ linearly independent from them. Then $Ax \ne By + Cz$ for $z \ne 0$ but $Ax = Bx$.